# C how to make a scanset stop when at certain length or when reading specific char

Tags: c, scanf

I have a string that consists of 3 parts (start, middle, end).
The middle part is encapsulated in `''` and it always contains one char or more (could be several hundred).
I want to only store the first 15 chars of this part if it's longer than 15 chars. Otherwise, I can just store the whole part.

```
char result1[16], result2[16];
char *str1 = "placeholder 'this is more than 15 chars' placeholder";
char *str2 = "placeholder 'this is less' placeholder";

sscanf(str1, "%*[^']'%15[^']'%*[^']", result1);
sscanf(str2, "%*[^']'%15[^']'%*[^']", result2);

printf("|%s|", result1);
printf("|%s|", result2);

//Expected output result1: "|this is more th|"
//Expected output result2: "|this is less|"
```

Keep in mind I am interested in one `sscanf` to handle both cases.
The above example might appear to work, but sometimes in the case of `str2` the scanset will continue to eat all 15 chars even if it has met its delimiter `'`.

Is there a way to make the scanset stop at its delimiter only if it has eaten less than 15 chars?

Comment: IMO you are fighting with the wrong tool for the job. Use `strchr` to find where the two `'` are, subtract the pointers for the length, and restrict that length for `memcpy` if more than 15. Finish with a terminating nul.

Comment: I think what you're written should work. `%15[^']` should never eat a `'` character.

Comment: There's no need for the second `%*[^']` in each format string.

Comment: I get the expected result when I run your code. Can you provide sample data where it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: You would only run into problems if you tried to extract a second variable from part 3. That will fail because `%15[^']` will leave the rest of the middle part in the input stream.

Comment: pluto9800, "sometimes in the case of str2 the scanset will continue to eat all 15 chars even if it has met its delimiter '." is highly suspicious.  Post code that demos that failing.

Comment: pluto9800, The final `"'%*[^']"` serves no purpose.  Why do you think it is useful?

Comment: pluto9800, What should happened with `"placeholder 'this is more than 15 chars but lacks a final single quote mark";`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that both the start and end part also contains valuable information. Therefore as @Barmar mentioned stuff is still left uneaten when the middle part is more than 15 chars, causing trouble when scanning the end part. I left the `%*[^']` parts in just to temp eat the placeholder parts even though they are not necessary

Comment: @pluto9800   In general, a single `sscanf()` cannot meet your parsing of _start, middle, end_ unless each pieces is at least 16 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a more robust alternative with error checking.

```
char *get_middle(char *dest, size_t sz, const char *s) {
  if (dest == NULL || sz == 0) return NULL;
  char *first = strchr(s, '\''); 
  if (first == NULL) return NULL;
  first++;
  char *second = strchr(first, '\''); 
  if (second == NULL) return NULL;
  size_t len = second - first;
  if (len == 0) return NULL;
  if (len >= sz) len = sz - 1;
  dest[len] = 0; 
  return memcpy(dest, first, len);
}
```